# PHP Session is ending unexpectedly

Tags: php, html, session, web

I have got a session up and running in PHP, but for some reason when I click a page sometimes, the session seems to end unexpectedly. 
FOR EXAMPLE:
I have a simple user login page (just username):
INDEX.PHP

```
<h1>User Sign-In:</h1>

<form name="login" action="main.php" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

MAIN.PHP

```
<?php
session_save_path(trim(`echo ~`).'/php_sessions'); session_start();
$_SESSION['username']= $_POST["username"];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
    }
else
    header('Location:./index.php');
?>

<body>

<?php
    echo "Hello, your username is: " . $_SESSION["username"];
?>
<a href="./main.php">Store</a> | <a href="./basket.php">Basket</a> | <a href="./about.php">About</a> | <a href="./logout.php">Logout</a>


<form name="select1"action="" method="GET">
<select name="higherorlower">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="greaterthan">Greater Than</option>
    <option value="lowerthan">Lower Than</option>
</select>
Price:<input type="text" name="price"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

BASKET.PHP

```
<?php
session_save_path(trim(`echo ~`).'/php_sessions'); session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
    }
else
    header('Location:.');
?>

<body>
<?php
    echo "Hello, your username is: " . $_SESSION["username"];
?>


<a href="./main.php">Store</a> | <a href="#">Basket</a> | <a href="./about.php">About</a> | <a href="./logout.php">Logout</a>

<h2>
You're currently on the basket page!
</h2>
```

So say I type in my username and it takes me to the MAIN.PHP fine and displays my username fine, I then click the basket page and it also displays my username fine, but when I click from the BASKET.PHP to the MAIN.PHP it looses the username and displays nothing....

I have no idea what is going on and any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but when I click from the BASKET.PHP to the MAIN.PHP it looses the
>   username and displays nothing....

That is because you are assigning

```
$_SESSION['username']= $_POST["username"];
```

on your **`main.php`** ,since there is no POST value there (as of now) , it gets overwritten.

Change your code on your **`main.php`** file like this

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    if(isset($_POST["username"]))
    {
    $_SESSION['username']= $_POST["username"];
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location:./index.php');
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay, I have changed the code in the MAIN.php to what you said, but when click the "Store" button on my navbar from the BASKET.PHP page, it still takes me back to the index.php (login page). I really am baffed?

Answer (score 0):

Just modified your code at `MAIN.php`. Now it should work.

```
 session_start();

 session_save_path(trim(`echo ~`).'/php_sessions');    

if(!empty($_POST["username"])){
   $_SESSION['username']= $_POST["username"];
   $username = $_POST["username"]; 
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
 header('location: index.php');
}
```